# Spring RestTemplate most suitable method for sending some data and expecting no return

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Spring offers three ways in which we could send data to server, **POST**, **PUT** and **Exchange**.

I have a requirement, where I am just sending out an **ID** and a **SecretKey** to server to notify some action, and I am expecting no return from server.

For sending this data I am using `MultiValueMap`

Presently I am using `postForObject` with `ResponseType` as null, but at runtime it is giving me error that `ResponseType` can not be null. So, what would be the best way to handle such scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ResponseEntity` with `Void`

```
ResponseEntity<Void> result = template.get().exchange(
                <Url>, HttpMethod.PUT, null,
                Void.class);
```